# Работа с двумя мониторами Wpf MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Можете подсказать, вот у меня есть 2 монитора и мне нужно по нажатию кнопки перенести окно WPF на другой монитор и при повторном нажатии кнопки вернуть обратно (на первоначальный монитор). Получается только перенести на второй монитор, а обратно не получается. Код который имеется на данный момент.

```
RefreshDisplayCommand = new RelayCommand( () => Display(Screen.AllScreens[1]));

private void Display(Screen screen = null)
    {
        if (screen == null)
        {
            if (Screen.AllScreens.Length>1) return;
            screen = Screen.AllScreens[1];
        }

        var bounds = screen.Bounds;

        mWindow.Left = bounds.Left + mWindow.Left;
        mWindow.Top = bounds.Top + mWindow.Top;
    }
```

Comment: Ну так вы же сами монитор указали `screen = Screen.AllScreens[1];`

Comment: Да. Получается нужно получить текущий монитор, на котором запущено приложение, но не получается его получить. Может не так вообще все делаю.

Comment: А в чем проблема запомнить первоначальную позицию?

Comment: Геннадий П, это как?

Answer (score 0):

При нажатии на кнопку проверяйте координаты вашего окна, в зависимости от от того больше ли Margin.Top или Margin.Left размера основного окна выполняйте перемещение:
(В теории должно работать)

```
if(Screen.AllScreens.Length > 1)
{
    var a = Screen.AllScreens[0].WorkingArea;
    if (MainWindow.Margin.Left > a.Width || MainWindow.Margin.Top > a.Height)
    {
        RefreshDisplayCommand = new RelayCommand( () => Display(Screen.AllScreens[0]));
    }
    else 
    {
        RefreshDisplayCommand = new RelayCommand( () => Display(Screen.AllScreens[1]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Артур Франк, не получается. переходит на второй монитор на второй клик, на третий клик, окно вообще пропадает

Comment: Ну это значит у вас в вашей функции неправильный расчет координат вот в этом месте. каогда вы переходите на первый экран должно быть вычитание по идее. `mWindow.Left = bounds.Left + mWindow.Left;mWindow.Top = bounds.Top + mWindow.Top;`